# Expectations from Service Fabric Reliable Services Reliable Collections

Tags: performance, azure, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateful, reliable-message-delivery

I am considering to store a new generated orderIDs in Service Fabric.

- Requirement
  :  By pass 1000 orders in a second.

I. Should I store this reliable Dictionary if the performance is needed ?

II. What are the performance considerations ?

III. What is the Service Fabric Reliable Collection Capacity

[image]

**Reference**

**Reliable Services Reliable Collections**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-reliable-collections

**service fabric dotnet performance** (No result page )

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/service-fabric-dotnet-performance/tree/master/ServiceLoadTest

Comment: Do the orderIDs need to be persisted? In that case using reliable collections are a good fit since the data resides closest to where it is used. In terms of performance that is a good thing. (Concurren) collections are in-memory only.

Comment: You probably don't even need to use reliable collections, many database stores can easily handle that throughput!

Comment: Is there a performance comparison available  where I can compare DB,Redis and service fabric ?

Comment: [StatePersistence(StatePersistence.Persisted)]  Does this affect the performance

Answer (score 1):

If you push 1000 orders from a single client at once then this can be handled without issues.

If each order is pushed individually and you need to ensure a throughput of a thousand per second, you should definitely use partitioning.

You should also use and monitor health metrics for your actual throughput and act on it by adding more nodes to your cluster when needed.